# Reading and segmenting a text file vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to segment the text inbetween datetime's in a text file. I have very limited knowledge in programming so any help would be appreciated.

This is currently my code for reading but i have many problems with it. Suggestions?

```
Private Sub Read_report_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim dict_report As New Dictionary(Of DateTime, String)
    Dim strDateTimeKey As String = DateTime.Now.ToString()
    Dim strRawValue As String = "sdfsdfsdf\n\nsdfsdfsdf"

    Dim dateTimeKey As String = DateTime.Parse(Text)

    dict_report.Add(dateTimeKey, strRawValue)

    Console.WriteLine(dict_report(dateTimeKey).ToString())
End Sub

Function Read() As Dictionary(Of DateTime, String)

    Dim dict_report As New Dictionary(Of DateTime, String)
    Dim sR As StreamReader = New StreamReader("systemrequest.txt")



    Dim strInfo As String = ""
    Dim prevDateTimeKey As New DateTime

    Dim currentline As String = sR.ReadLine()
    prevDateTimeKey = DateTime.Parse(currentline)
    Do While Not currentline Is Nothing
        Dim dateTimeKey As New DateTime

        If DateTime.TryParse(currentline, dateTimeKey) Then
            dict_report.Add(prevDateTimeKey, strInfo)
            prevDateTimeKey = dateTimeKey
            strInfo = ""
        Else

            strInfo += "\n" + currentline

        End If


        currentline = sR.ReadLine()
    Loop

    'dict_report.Item(DateTime.Now)
    sR.Close()
    Return dict_report
```

Currently it returns an error of having the same key as prevDateTimekey.

The raw data that is being read is as follows:

```
27/05/2015 12:20:32 PM
wat0021
HARDWARE ISSUE1
27/05/2015 1:22:49 PM
Username
HARDWARE ISSUE2
27/05/2015 1:53:16 PM
Username
HARDWARE ISSUE3
27/05/2015 10:37:44 PM
Username
HARDWARE ISSUE3
27/05/2015 10:39:42 PM
Username
HARDWARE ISSUE4
27/05/2015 10:39:58 PM
Username
HARDWARE ISSUE5
27/05/2015 10:41:03 PM
Username
HARDWARE ISSUE
27/05/2015 10:42:08 PM
Username
HARDWARE ISSUE
27/05/2015 10:43:25 PM
Username
HARDWARE ISSUE
27/05/2015 10:43:58 PM
Username
HARDWARE ISSUE
27/05/2015 10:44:45 PM
Username
HARDWARE ISSUE
```

Comment: That is how a Dictionary works: each key must be unique so that you can retrieve the values easily.  We have no idea what the data looks like, but at first glance, using `DateTime` as the key *may* be a bad idea: a single clock tick results in a different key.

Comment: I cant tell what you are trying to do with `dateTimeKey` and `prevDateTimeKey`.  They have to be unique, so it seems that the last read DT value should be the key.  In order to access the value though, you will have to know the *exact second* of the key.

Comment: @Plutonix, I am attempting to look for the date time values in the data and read the text inbetween two date time values. If that helps to interpret the code :)

Comment: "in between" makes no difference.  If the format is DT // UserName // Issue, then process them 3 lines at a time.  I'd create a class to store those 3 items and then store them in a `List(Of HardwareItem)` - a DateTime key in a dictionary will end up being problematic

Comment: I'm trying to read each line and if it fits as a DateTime, if it fits then it saves that as a key for the data until the next DateTime. Its test data for a data logging project where the number of lines can range from 3 to any higher amount. Sorry, I haven't made all this exactly clear.

Comment: If this worked, then please click the checkmark to move this off the UnAnswered list.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I might handle this.  First, a class to store the info for an entry:

```
Public Class HardwareIssue
    Public Property UserName As String
    Public Property ItemDate As DateTime
    Public Property Report As List(Of String)

    Public Sub New()
        Report = New List(Of String)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Instead of a collection of strings for the report data, you could concat them into a single string.  I have no idea which is more appropriate.

Then process the file, making a new Hardware issue item for each "block".  The lot of these are then stored in a `List(of HardwareIssue)`.  Note: the final code might need to be tweaked depending on any "quirks" in the real data which we are unaware of.  One example is malformed or incomplete blocks - the remedy would depend on the cause.

```
Dim item As HardwareIssue
Dim dtItem As DateTime
Dim txt As String
Dim HWItems As New List(Of HardwareIssue)

Using sr As New StreamReader("C:\Temp\hwreport.txt")
    ' get a line
    txt = sr.ReadLine
    ' loop until it is empty
    Do Until String.IsNullOrEmpty(txt)
        ' new item
        item = New HardwareIssue

        ' the txt is a Date, it is the start of a "block"
        If DateTime.TryParse(txt, dtItem) Then
            item.ItemDate = dtItem          ' store date
            dtItem = Nothing                ' clear temp var

            item.UserName = sr.ReadLine     ' read and store username

            txt = sr.ReadLine               ' read a line

            ' loop to keep reading report text until
            '   we run out of lines OR see a date
            Do Until ((String.IsNullOrEmpty(txt)) Or (DateTime.TryParse(txt, dtItem)))
                item.Report.Add(txt)        ' add report text
                txt = sr.ReadLine           ' read a line
            Loop
            HWItems.Add(item)               ' add this item to the list
        Else
            ' this is bad news: the first line needs to be a date
            '   read a new line to find a date, but this might skip a 
            '   partial first block
            txt = sr.ReadLine
        End If
        ' if txt from the last sr.Readline in the Report DO loop is empty
        ' the job is done, exit.  If it is a Date which ended            
        ' the loop, txt still contains it and its ready for the 
        ' TryParse test at the top of the loop
    Loop

End Using              ' close, dispose of sr

Return HWItems
```

Comment: Okay! That's look like it makes sense. I've got school this morning but I will give the code a go after. Thank you